# Prove using definition of integral $ \int_{1}^{a}\frac{1}{x}dx=\int_{b}^{ab}\frac{1}{x}dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I have to prove by using the definition of integral

> $\int_{1}^{a}\frac{1}{x}dx=\int_{b}^{ab}\frac{1}{x}dx$ for $a>1,b>1$

here is my attempt

let $P_1=\{1,a\}$ & $P_2=\{a,ab\}$ & $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$  then $P_1$ is partition of $[1,a]$ & $P_2$ is partition of $[a,ab]$

now
$L(P_1,f)=\frac{1}{a}(a-1), U(P_1,f)=(a-1)$

$L(P_2,f)=\frac{1}{ab}(ba-b)\Rightarrow\frac{1}{a}(a-1), U(P_2,f)=\frac{1}{b}(b-ab)\Rightarrow(a-1)$

$L(P_1,f)<I_1<U(P_1,f)$

$L(P_2,f)<I_2<U(P_2,f)$

since $L(P_1,f)=L(P_2,f),U(P_1,f)=U(P_2,f)$ and $I_1,I_2$ unique

since this is true for any $a$ when $a\rightarrow1$  $I_1=I_2$

Comment: You need to do the argument for an *arbitrary* partition $P_1$ of $[1,a]$ and corresponding partition $P_2$ of $[b,ab]$. (You seem to be assuming $I_1$ and $I_2$ are unique, so you already have established that the function is integrable on the respective intervals.)

Comment: @TedShifrin my argument is not a genarized one right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $P$ is a partition of $[1,a]$ given by $1=x_0< x_1<\ldots < x_{n-1}<x_n=a $ then $bP$ is a partition of $[b,ab]$ given by $b=y_0<y_1<\ldots<y_{n-1}<y_n=ab$ with $y_k=bx_k$. If we consider $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$, we have that:
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f(x_k)(x_{k+1}-x_k) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f(y_k)(y_{k+1}-y_k) $$
as well as:
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n}f(x_k)(x_{k}-x_{k-1}) = \sum_{k=1}^{n}f(y_k)(y_{k}-y_{k-1}). $$
$f(x)$ is a continuous (and convex) function over $\mathbb{R}^+$, hence it is Riemann-integrable over any closed interval belonging to $\mathbb{R}^+$. For any partition of $[1,a]$ leading to some Riemann sum, there is a partition of $[b,ab]$ leading to exactly the same sum (and vice-versa). It follows that:
$$ \int_{1}^{a}\frac{dx}{x}=\int_{b}^{ab}\frac{dx}{x}.$$